# How to break line in SQL STUFF Query

Tags: sql, asp.net

How to break the line in merged row in sql

Table:

```
UserID      Country   VisitedState
----------  -------  -------------
1            MY        KL
1            MY        Penang
1            MY        Johor*
```

Currently output:

```
UserID      Country   VisitedState
----------  -------  -------------
1            MY        KL, Penang, Johor
```

Expecting output:

```
UserID      Country   VisitedState
----------  -------  -------------
                       KL
1            MY        Penang
                       Johor
```

I am using stuff select with the ', ' beginning in the query. Is there any code to replace the comma to perform the break line?

Comment: post your query to get your current output

Comment: You REALLY need to move that display logic to the UI layer rather than doing it in SQL.  As it stands now, you want to center the "repeating" values in the group of unique values.  The Display layer (report, app, web page, etc.) is MUCH better suited for this type of display tweaking than SQL.

Comment: use `\r\n` instead of `,`?

Comment: I suspect you are using something like - `STUFF((SELECT ',' + ..... ), 1, 1, '')`, simply replace your comma with `CHAR(13)` --> `STUFF((SELECT CHAR(13) + .....), 1, 1, '')`

Comment: Hi all, thanks for the replies.
My query is like this:
SELECT U.UserID, U.Country, stuff( (SELECT ', '+VisitedState FROM VisitedState VS WHERE U.UserID = VS.UserID FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'varchar(max)') ,1,1,'') AS StateVisited FROM [User] U;

CHAR(13) is not working for this query

Answer (score 5):

LineBreak does not work in STUFF. You can use this trick :

```
Replace(STUFF((SELECT ','+'##@@$$$' + .....), 1, 1, ''),'##@@$$$',CHAR(13)+CHAR(10))
Replace(STUFF((SELECT ','+'##@@$$$' + .....), 1, 1, ''),'##@@$$$','<br>')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try this trick:

```
select 'break'+char(13)+char(10)+' the '+char(13)+char(10)+'lines'
```

If query output in Management Studio is setted to TEXT you ill see:

```
-------------------
break
 the 
lines
```

Note if in Management Studio the query output is setted to GRID (default) you ill not see it.

Also formating text SQL side for reports, UI, etc is a **bad practice!** In general that kind of "logic" is better placed in the first layer||client-side app

**Edit:**

It works, bet you don't payed attention to my note...
To prove prepared this example on [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/78f1f/1)

Note: You must set Output to **plain text**
The default Tabular output ill not show the line breaks for obvious reasons

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for the reply.
The trick u gave me is not working in my sql management studio.
The output is:
'break the lines' without any linebreak

Comment: LineBreak does not work in STUFF.